# Connecttion problem port 443 through azure vm public IP

Tags: azure-virtual-network

I have done all the settings for ssl certificate in azure vm. it is working fine to use the particular port 443 through private ip address of azure VM. I have added the security inbound rule in the azure virtual network for port 443. but still not working through public IP. Please help me.

Comment: Do you ensure that the port 443 is listening on 0.0.0.0 inside your Azure VM?

Comment: Please tell me how to make listener in azure VM. I make the inbound rule  for the port 443 in azure VM firewall.

Comment: What's an application on Azure VM? Is it a Windows or Linux VM? You need to Inject the certificate into the VM and configure IIS with a TLS binding. The port should bind with 0.0.0.0.

Comment: It is an asp.net application on window VM. I have injected  the certificates and configure IIS with TLS binding. Should we do 0.0.0.0 port binding in Azure VM or in  NSG inbound rule ?

Comment: On Azure VM, bind 0.0.0.0 with port 443 in IIS.

Comment: I tried but could not bind  because of the values does not fall within the expected range.